# Why does this answer have upvotes even though it doesn't solve the problem asked?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes, specific-answer

The answer in [context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59480180/10155936). The error (as mentioned in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480136/10155936)) clearly indicates that a push will be rejected (until it's a force push).

Comment: There is no evidence of suspicious voting on that post. Sometimes, people will find an answer to be useful, even though it doesn't *directly* answer the question. As long as people aren't committing vote fraud, they are welcome to vote however they like on posts. The reason(s) may not always be obvious.

Comment: I guess at least 5 people found it useful.

Comment: It’s very likely that other people had an easier version of the same problem the OP had: the same error but without whatever additional issue prevented that answer from helping the OP.

Comment: By the way, if you see a horribly wrong answer that has inexplicably garnered a number of upvotes, then you may consider flagging it for moderator attention, asking us to check for possible vote fraud. We will be happy to do so. Sometimes the smell will alert us to something rotten; other times, it's a false positive. But we're happy to investigate, since this isn't really something that you can check for yourself, and regular users are our eyes and ears out there.

Comment: 5 helpful votes on 3 distinct posts, all cast within a minute, smells pretty rotten.  Fear not, such users have two incurable problems that will eventually expose them.  They don't have enough patience and don't know when to stop.